# Alternative to function for dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that returns a list of projectIDs at the moment. I want to extend this to return some extra information to determine if a specific user has access to this project.

To determine if a user has access I need to look up the user in a table called 'Project_XXX' where XXX is the projectID. Yes, this is shocking database design but sadly there is nothing I can do about it. My first instinct was that I could use a function as such:

```
SELECT ProjectID WHERE [criteria] AND myfunc(ProjectID, @username)=1
```

However, because the lookup needs to run dynamic SQL it tells me that I can't do this.

This leaves me with the option of putting my logic in a stored procedure but then the syntax of my select is not simple.

The way I can think of to do it is to run the select to get the list of projectIDs and then run a cursor over that table calling my stored procedure but I stopped thinking there because it seems far too complicated...

So is there some way I can do what I want with similarly simple syntax to above? Is there some way to get a user function to return based on dynamic SQL? Is there a nice way to use stored procedures as I have above? I'm sure I am missing something obvious - I rarely need to do anything complicated with SQL though. ;-)

I should also reiterate that I *know* that the underlying problem is with the stupid individual project tables but this is not something that can be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to create a view from all the project_xxx tables. Something like:

```
CREATE VIEW SecurityTable
AS
SELECT 'Project_1', User, HasAccess
FROM   Project_1
UNION
SELECT 'Project_2', User, HasAccess
FROM   Project_2
UNION
SELECT 'Project_3', User, HasAccess
FROM   Project_3
etc...
```

Then you can simply query your view as though the database had been designed properly in the first place ;-)

```
SELECT ProjectID, User
FROM   SecurityTable
WHERE [criteria]
AND   HasAccess=1
```

---

As you state that you will be frequently adding new project tables, I would suggest you could have a security table populated with a dynamic query every morning. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE Project_1 (
    Usr varchar(20),
    HasAccess bit)
GO
CREATE TABLE Project_2 (
    Usr varchar(20),
    HasAccess bit)
GO
CREATE TABLE SecurityTable (
    Usr varchar(20),
    HasAccess bit)
GO


INSERT INTO Project_1 (Usr, HasAccess) VALUES ('Kermit', 1)
INSERT INTO Project_1 (Usr, HasAccess) VALUES ('MissPiggy', 1)
INSERT INTO Project_2 (Usr, HasAccess) VALUES ('Beaker', 1)
INSERT INTO Project_2 (Usr, HasAccess) VALUES ('TheCount', 0)
GO

Create Procedure LoadSecurityTable 
AS
    DELETE * FROM SecurityTable

    EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 
        @command1 = 'INSERT INTO SecurityTable (Usr, HasAccess) SELECT Usr, HasAccess FROM ?',
        @whereand = 'AND o.name LIKE ''Project_%'''
GO

EXEC LoadSecurityTable
SELECT * FROM SecurityTable
```

Comment: I had considered that but I suspect that having to add a project to the view each time a new one is created is compunding the problem. Unless there is a way that I can create that view with some kind of dynamic sql so I don't need to update it...? :)

Comment: I've updated my answer. Oddly I wanted to put `TRUNCATE TABLE` instead of `DELETE * FROM`, but StackOverflow wouldn't let me!!

Comment: That new part wth sp_MSForEachTable looks like it is quite promising I wish I could give you another +1 for that. ;-)

Comment: You could also maintain the view with a DDL trigger hooked to the CREATE_TABLE event, so you wouldn't have to manually change the view whenever a new table is added. However, beware of sp_MSForEachTable. I've documented how its cousin sp_MSForEachDB skip databases, and since it is written in a similar way... I would prefer to write my own cursor or string concat dynamic SQL to build that list.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Didn't know that these functions weren't reliable - have you got a link - sounds interesting? I agree with the thrust of your point - these are undocumented functions, and a cursor iterating through `sysobjects` or similar would be better.

Comment: `sysobjects` is no good either IMHO if you want the solution to last - this is a backward compatibility view. I would much prefer to use `sys.tables`. For issues with the procedure see https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2010/12/29/a-more-reliable-and-more-flexible-sp-msforeachdb.aspx and http://mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=2201 - the main problem is the type of cursor they declare. If you use `LOCAL STATIC FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY` you won't have any issues.

Comment: With a bit of struggling (converting to my actual db schema which is more complciated than the example above) this has done me a charm. Loving the MSForEachTable. :)

Comment: Hmm... and now I've read the reliability comments and think that I might just write my own loop since its relatively simple what I'm doing to populate that table.

Answer (score 1):

As you seem to know, you cannot run dynamic SQL or call a stored procedure from within a function.

There is a very ugly workaround that involves calling a batch script (.bat) from within your function using [`xp_cmdshell`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260689%28v=sql.80%29.aspx), and using [`sp_executesql`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) in the batch script to execute the dynamic SQL.

However, I'd go with RB's view solution for the sake of simplicity!

Comment: Yeah, that is sounding like a workaround that is going to be a PITA at some point. :)