# SQL Function, Column as a variable

Tags: sql-server-2008

new to SQL programming,
I have this function which works well:

```
(
@clientId AS int
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
declare @result nvarchar(50);
declare @lastDate Date;
declare @dateBefore Date;
declare @count float;
set @count = (select  MAX(A1c)-MIN(A1c) as change from
(select A1c from 
( select top 2 * from vw_MasterView where clientId = @clientId order by vw_masterView.LastVisitDate desc  ) as vw
group by A1c) as hh);
RETURN @count
end;
```

Since I will be repeating this function to calculate other columns from the MasterView; I would like to change A1c to a variable, as the following:

```
(
@clientId AS int,
@lab AS nvarchar(50)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
declare @result nvarchar(50);
declare @lastDate Date;
declare @dateBefore Date;
declare @count float;
set @count = (select  MAX(@lab)-MIN(@lab) as change from
(select @lab from 
( select top 2 * from vw_MasterView where clientId = @clientId order by vw_masterView.LastVisitDate desc  ) as vw
group by @lab) as hh);
RETURN @count
end;
```

I got the following errors:

```
Msg 164, Level 15, State 1, Procedure fn_changeA1c, Line 22
Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.
Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Procedure fn_changeA1c, Line 22
No column name was specified for column 1 of 'hh'.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No dynamic SQL in a function, sorry. Some alternatives: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430143/alternative-to-function-for-dynamic-sql ... or, use a procedure instead of a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use stored procedure instead of function.

```
create procedure myprocedure
    @clientId AS int,
    @lab AS nvarchar(50)
    AS
BEGIN
    declare @result nvarchar(50);
    declare @lastDate Date;
    declare @dateBefore Date;
    declare @count float;
    declare @sql nvarchar(500);
    set @sql = 'select  MAX(' + @lab + ')-MIN(' + @lab + ') as change from
    (select ' + @lab + ' from 
    ( select top 2 * from vw_MasterView where clientId = ' + convert(nvarchar, @clientId) + ' order by    vw_masterView.LastVisitDate desc  ) as vw
    group by ' + @lab + ') as hh';
    execute sp_executesql @sql;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a much better approach.

Comment: I got an error Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'select  MAX(A1c)-MIN(A1c)

Comment: I have modified my answer. Because @sql variable is nvarchar, the variables that inside the sql statement must be nvarchar. If variable is not nvarchar, you can use convert function.